# Volume problem (begginer integration)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Not sure if this is correct, can stack exchange help me confirm or deny my work?

determine the volume of revolution by revolving the region bounded by $y=2$, $y=\ln(x)$, $y=0$ and $x=0$ around the y axis

This region is illustrated in the attached photo [image: boundarea]

it is clear that $y=\ln(x)$ and $y=2$ intersect at at $(e^2,x)$ given that
$\ln(x)=2$, $e^2=x$. The lines in respect to $y$ are $x=0, x=e^y$

I believe the best option is to integrate with respect to y as a series of circles, where a circle is given by the eqn: $A=\pi r^{2}$

so the volume:

$$\begin{align}
V&=\int_{0}^{2}\pi[(e^{y})^{2}-(0)^{2}]\:dy\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{2}[e^{2y}-0]\:dy\\
&=\pi[\int_{0}^{2}e^{2y}\:dy]\\
&=\pi\big[[\frac{1}{2}e^{2y}]_{0}^{2}\big]\\
&=\pi[\frac{1}{2}e^{4}-\frac{1}{2}]\\
&=1/2\pi[e^{4}-1]\end{align}$$

My questions:

1. because it is a definite integral can I just ignore the integral of $0$ (which should be a constant)
2. $y=\ln(x)$ crosses into the first quadrant at $x=1/2$ will this change how i set up the integral
3. am i missing elements, ignoring important information?

Thanks

p.s feel free to fix my LaTex

Comment: $e^{2y}-0$ is simply $0$, no need to worry about it. But if you do, and when integrating put a constant there, the constant will cancel when you evaluate at $2$ and subtract the result of evaluating at $0$.  The integral you set up is the right one.

Comment: If you decide to include the integral of zero, when you take the *definite* integral, the constant in the upper limit and the constant in the lower limit will be the same, and thus will cancel out.

Comment: okay thanks, so generally in *any* definite integral, the constants will nullify each other.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your questions in order:

1. I am not too sure what you mean by ignoring the integral of $0$ because there are no instances where you are integrating $0$ in this problem. Please elaborate and I'll edit this answer with a response.
2. So first off, $y=\ln{x}$ crosses the $x$-axis at $x=1$. Now to answer your question, it will not change how you set up the integral. This is due to the fact that you are interpreting the graph as a function of $y$. Because of this, the only values that matter when setting up your integrals (namely the lower and upper limits of integration) are $y$ values. You need only determine these two values when setting up your integral. The $x$ value where the graph crosses into quadrant I is irrelevant as that value will be computed and taken into consideration when you integrate the function.
3. It seems that at least on a conceptual level, you understand what is going on. You got the most critical information

Comment: good, I can see that y=ln(x) going from 0 to 2 on the y axis is the only important part of the integral, considering there is no non-bound area between the y axis and y=ln(x)

Comment: I guess the least important question remains, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The volume you want to calculate is bounded by $x=0$, $x=\mathrm{e}^2$ and $y=0$, $y=ln(x)$. Then you revolve this volume around the $x\text{-axis}$, starting from $0$ to $2\pi$.
You can express this volume as 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} (\int_0^{ln(x)} (\int_0^{\mathrm{e}^2} dx)dy)dz$$